# What does it mean to run bittorrent app over Tor?

Tags: bittorrent

I know I should avoid running bittorrent application over Tor, but I do not understand what does it mean. I should not browse the web using Tor browser and run bittorrent application at the same time?

I am just learning english, so sorry for probably stupid question
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'Using Tor' means that network communication from a given software package is going through the Tor network instead of using the network directly.

Many software packages, from operating system updates to browsers to bittorrent clients, send data over the internet. If software is using Tor then all their network data is going through Tor. Usually software has to be specifically configured to use Tor, so unless you have explicitly configured your software to use Tor assume that it is communicating directly over the internet. The Tor Browser Bundle is browser software that is configured to use the Tor network with no additional configuration.

It is possible to use Tor for some software applications (such as the Tor Browser Bundle) while also using other software that is not using Tor (such as your bittorrent client). Be warned that software not using Tor will provide any listening third party considerable information about what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Tor Browser Bundle, your bittorrent client will not use Tor, unless you have configured it to do so. In this case, I do not believe that running the bittorrent client while using the Tor Browser is a problem. If anything, the bittorrent client generates non-Tor traffic that might help hide Tor use, especially if you are using obfuscated bridges.

It is difficult to configure bittorrent clients to properly use Tor. If you have tried that, and the client is performing well, much of its traffic is probably not being routed through Tor. Given Tor's high latency and low bandwidth, the client will not perform very well if you do manage to configure it properly. And in the process, it will max out many circuits, hog relays, and interfere with other Tor users. That is why people advise against doing it.